# How to create React's new static function getDerivedStateFromProps as a lifecycle method using an HoC in the recompose library?

Tags: reactjs, higher-order-components, recompose, react-lifecycle

Recently it has come out that soon React will be deprecating `componentWillReceiveProps` and in it's place is the new static function `getDerivedStateFromProps`. [See more here](https://medium.com/@baphemot/whats-new-in-react-16-3-d2c9b7b6193b)

I am currently migrating my apps to this new API, but am having an issue with`getDerivedStateFromProps`, due to the fact that I am using the recompose library for higher order components. We make the use of `componentWillReceive` props through the library's lifecycle object.

So before moving to the new API, I had this:

```
export function someHoC () {
  return compose(
    lifecycle({
      componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
        const { fetch } = nextProps
          if (shouldFetch(this.props, nextProps)) {
             fetch()
          }
      }
    })
  )
}
```

This has now changed to the following:

```
export function someHoC () {
  return compose(
    lifecycle({
      getDerivedStateFromProps (nextProps) {
          const { fetch } = nextProps
          if (shouldFetch(this.props, nextProps)) {
             fetch()
          }
      }
    })
  )
}
```

However, `getDerivedStateFromProps` needs to be static, so I am getting the warning regarding that and don't know how to handle it.

> warning.js?7f205b4:33 Warning: lifecycle(MyComponent): getDerivedStateFromProps() is defined as an instance method and will be ignored. Instead, declare it as a static method.

What can I do to pass it in as a static lifecycle method into my component?

Comment: show me whats in your do stuff

Comment: I'll update the OP, but it's irrelevant to the problem, which is why I chose to remove it.

Comment: You could use `setStatic`, but that will actually modify the base component, which might not be what you want.

Comment: I did consider that, but it does not solve my problem due to exactly that.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `getDerivedStateFromProps` you need to declare it as a [static method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static):

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps() {...}
```

Obviously, this makes `getDerivedStateFromProps` static, which means you can't call it the same as you could call `componentWillReceiveProps`.

If a static method doesn't work for you, you can move your logic into `componentDidUpdate` to silence the warning. However this can cause an additional render if you call `setState()` from this method. Depending on what happens when you resolve your `fetch()`, this may work for you.

You can also replace `componentWillReceiveProps` with `UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps` ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops)), which will work the same way. However, due to the upcoming async rendering feature, [this could cause some issues](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following inside your lifecycle

`setStatic('getDerivedStateFromProps', (nextProps, prevState) => {})`  and store previous values in component state for retrieving it from `prevState` argument

Comment: outside the lifecycle.